# Compare rows and select max value

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach, max

I have the following table:

```
FileName | SubFileName | TotalPlayersCount |
-------------------------------------------
AAA      |     SF1     |        11         |     
AAA      |     SF2     |        5          |    
AAA      |     SF3     |        3          |  
BBB      |     SF1     |        8          |    
BBB      |     SF2     |        15         |   
BBB      |     SF3     |        2          | 
CCC      |     SF1     |        5          |      
CCC      |     SF2     |        10         |    
CCC      |     SF3     |        20         |
```

As you can see, each `FileName` has 3 different `SubfileName` ('SF1', 'SF2', 'SF3').

Each of these `SubfileName` have a different value for `TotalPlayersCount`.

I am trying to select the max value of the column `TotalPlayersCount` out of the three `SubfileName`, and this, *FOREACH* `FileName`.

The result should be:

```
FileName | SubFileName | TotalPlayersCount |
-------------------------------------------
AAA      |     SF1     |        11         | 
BBB      |     SF2     |        15         | 
CCC      |     SF3     |        20         |
```

I tried myself a couple of queries and this is the closest I've come to:

```
select distinct FileName, max(TotalPlayersCount) AS TotalPlayersCount
from dbo.MyTestTable
group by FileName
```

This is the result I get:

```
FileName | TotalPlayersCount |
------------------------------
AAA      |        11         | 
BBB      |        15         | 
CCC      |        20         |
```

So now I'm missing the `SubfileName` in the result.

Could you help me finding what's missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need for `SELECT DISTINCT` as you're already doing that GROUP BY.

Comment: How do we know which SubfileName to chose for a FileName?

Comment: All SubFileNames should be selected per FileName.
I thought about doing and SubFileName in ('SF1',SF2',SF3') but it doesn't work.

Comment: So you want 9 rows to be returned, each possible FileName/SubfileName combination?

Comment: I''l try to explain it better.
The goal is to find the max value of the column "TotalPlayersCount", per FileName.
Which means, each TotalPlayersCount value from SubFileName SF1 has to be compared with TotalPlayersCount value from SubFileName SF2 and with TotalPlayersCount value from SubFileName SF3.
The final result should be :

AAA      |     SF1     |        11         |      ......  

BBB      |     SF2     |        15         |     .....

CCC     |     SF3     |        20        |

Comment: Alright, I see. It's a pure coincidence you get the 3 different SubfileNames...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way, use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if there are no other row with same FileName that has a higher TotalPlayersCount:

```
select FileName, SubFileName, TotalPlayersCount 
from dbo.MyTestTable t1
where not exists (select 1 from dbo.MyTestTable t2
                  where t2.FileName = t1.FileName
                    and t2.TotalPlayersCount > t1.TotalPlayersCount)
```

`JOIN` version, perhaps better performance:

```
select t1.FileName, t1.SubFileName, t1.TotalPlayersCount 
from dbo.MyTestTable t1
JOIN (select FileName, max(TotalPlayersCount) as TotalPlayersCount
      from dbo.MyTestTable
      group by FileName) t2
  ON  t2.FileName = t1.FileName
  and t2.TotalPlayersCount = t1.TotalPlayersCount
```

Both queries will return both rows in case of a tie!

Comment: Thanks @jarlh, both solutions worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select fileName,subFileName,max(TotalPlayersCount )
from table_name 
group by filename
```

Comment: this will return wrong value (actually first occurrence) of `subFileName`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.FileName, a.SubFileName, a.TotalPlayersCount
FROM MyTestTable a INNER JOIN (SELECT FileName, max(TotalPlayersCount) AS TPC
                               FROM MyTestTable
                               GROUP BY FileName
                              ) b ON a.FileName = b.FileName AND
                                     a.TotalPlayersCount = b.TPC
ORDER BY a.FileName, a.SubFileName
```

The subquery returns the result you already have (no need for `DISTINCT` as jarlh mentioned). The result will be joined with the Table again to select the `SubFileName`.

Please note that if you have more than one `SubFileName` with the max value of `TotalPlayersCount` the first `SubFileName` will be picked, as it is part of the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Same as my second query. Will return both SubFileNames if it's a tie - no matter what the ORDER BY says.

Comment: You are totally right. But I think it's a valid answer ;) You were just too fast

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server - should work in MySQL as well.

```
SELECT  m.FileName, MIN(s.SubFileName) AS SubFileName, m.TotalPlayersCount
FROM    SOURCE_TABLE s
        INNER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT  FileName, MAX(TotalPlayersCount) AS TotalPlayersCount
            FROM    SOURCE_TABLE
            GROUP BY FileName ) m ON m.FileName = s.FileName AND
                 m.TotalPlayersCount = s.TotalPlayersCount
GROUP BY m.FileName, m.TotalPlayersCount
```

Comment: Did you try it? It will return what you are looking for. The sub-query ensures that we get one record per `FileName` - the one with the `MAX(TotalPlayersCount)`; and the join including the `TotalPlayersCount` will ensure only 1 returned record per `FileName`.

Comment: The only caveat is that if two `SubFileNames` for the same `FileName` have the same value; it will only return 1 of them - which aligns with your request; if you wanted it to return both the query could be adjusted accordingly